# How to do element wise multiplication for two 4D unequal size tensors in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have got a tensor A and Tensor B.

**Size of A** = [2,64,56,56]

**Size of B** = [2,64,29,29]

How can I perform `torch.mul(A,B)`? The tensors are of unequal size.

> RuntimeError: shape `[2, 64, 56, 56]` is invalid for input of size 107648

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the documentation here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.mul

There, you can read:

> The shapes of input and other must be broadcastable.

You can read about broadcastability here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics

Lastly, it probably makes sense to think about what you want to achieve. I'm not sure what you wanted such operation to do since to have the element-wise multiplication you need the tensors to have the same shapes.